# how to secure Azure WebRole svc service with ACS

Tags: wcf, azure, wcf-security, wif, acs

I'm struggling with securing IIS hosted svc WCF service hosted in Azure using WIF and ACS.

I found lot of how-tos here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg185939.aspx

I'm particularly interested in those describing how create secure WCF service and authenticate using certificate or username/password.

Now the ACS definition part is pretty clear. But when it comes to securing the service itself I struggle. I'm using WebRole and SVC file to expose the service and the configuration in how-to is done in code and I guess it won't work with azure webrole as well.

Any help on how to get this combination working would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a small clarification: if you rely on ACS then the authentication (in whatever form: certs / username/password, etc) will happen in ACS, not in your app. Your WCF service will simply expect a token issued by ACS and will remain largely ignorant of the type of authentication used.

Also, the actual implementation depends on whether you are creating a SOAP service or a REST one. Typically you have different token formats and protocols involved (e.g. SAML vs SWT, etc.)

Besides the how-tos you mentioned, take a look at the samples in [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx). Especially these:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446528.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh446531.aspx

Hope it helps

Comment: Another great sample if you're doing REST is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh127795.aspx - this demonstrates using OAuth 2.0 via SWT to a WCF service.

Comment: it seems like it is very hard to find a complete example of SOAP WCF service using ACS

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need to use a HttpModule to secure your service. The primary responsibility of this module is to read the Authorization header and create the claims.

Also make sure in the web.config  tag should contain

You can get the code for HttpModule from the below sample.

http://acs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ACS%20Windows%20Phone%20Sample

Look at the ProtectedResourceModule.cs

Joy